# XQuery adopters

Tags: xquery

From my understanding XQuery provides the most efficient method of manipulating XML. From that understanding, I would expect to see many implementations in the market place.

Can anybody provide the names of company's or organizations that have adopted XQuery into their deployments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are at least [56 implementations](http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/#implementations) of XQuery. I would say that is a lot.

Providing the names of company's that have adopted XQuery? How is that possible? I would say that every major company that uses XML also uses XQuery. Or, is on the way to use it.

I would suggest to send this question to the [XQuery Talk Mailing List](http://x-query.com/mailman/listinfo/talk).

But, maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Any company that uses one of those 56 implementations (or any other that has not yet been listed there) is evidently using XQuery. The commercial products usually have customer listings on their website.

Comment: @Dennis thanks for the links. That is probably a better forum for this question. I am looking for implementations for use as technology reference.

Comment: @grtjn Good point, I'll take a look!